# Face detection and loss function with a CNN model : regression problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I have labeled images with coordinates of a box surrounding the face (as labels) and I want to train a model to detect the box coordinates around a face. I transformed the box coordinates as it is common to in (x_middle, y_middle, width, height) / 255.
And I want my loss function be :

```
loss = (x_pred - x_true)**2+(y_pred - x_true)**2 + (np.sqrt(asb(w_pred))- np.sqrt(w_true))**2 + (np.sqrt(asb(h_pred)) - np.sqrt(h_tue)**2
```

w = width, h = height, x = middle of w, y = middle of h.

So far my code is :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, (x_mid,y_mid,w,h),      
test_size = 0.2)
    
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(192, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=(256,256,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(1024, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Dense(4))
    
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = ...)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_valid, y_valid), epoch = 5)
```

And I have no idea how to define the loss function with 4 multiples outputs like this in order that the model use it to calculate the loss ...

If anyone has an idea ?

Comment: What's exactly the problem? You have everything ready to go. create a function for computing loss function: for example: `def my_loss(y_true,y_pred): return ((x_pred - x_true)**2+(y_pred - x_true)**2 + (np.sqrt(asb(w_pred))- np.sqrt(w_true))**2 + (np.sqrt(asb(h_pred)) - np.sqrt(h_tue)**2)` and then pass it to compile function like this: `loss=my_loss`. Is it ok with you?

Comment: But how the model will understand what is x_pred, x_true, y_pred, y_true, w_pred, w_true, and h_pred, h_true ?

Comment: You are likely passing one sample and the corresponding label like `(x_true,y_true,w_true,h_true)`. The model move the input through layers, and will output 4 numbers like `(x_pred,y_pred,w_pred,h_pred)`. Now it has 2 arrays with shape `(1,4)`, which the first one is `y_true` and the second one is `y_pred`. Then it will pass both of them to your loss function and gets the output.